# JQuery check if JSON data contain a certain key

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to check if some JSON data contains a certain key and if it does, display that keys value, but I keep getting an error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'CurrentTextValue' of undefined`

How can I check if a certain key exists and if it does display its value.

```js
var carj = '[{ "Description": "SAAB 900 S CONVERTIBLE", "RegistrationYear": "1993", "CarMake": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "CarModel": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "MakeDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "ModelDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "EngineSize": { "CurrentTextValue": "1985" }, "BodyStyle": { "CurrentTextValue": "Motorbike" }, "FuelType": { "CurrentTextValue": "PETROL" }, "Variant": "", "Colour": "BLACK", "VehicleIdentificationNumber": "YS3AD75S1P7004905", "KType": "", "EngineNumber": "B202S3M03P032338" }]';

carj2 = $.parseJSON(carj);

if(carj2[0].NumberOfDoors.CurrentTextValue != '') {
console.log(carj2[0].NumberOfDoors.CurrentTextValue);
} else {
console.log('i dont have doors');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is `carj2[0].NumberOfDoors` undefined so `if(carj2[0].NumberOfDoors && carj2[0].NumberOfDoors.CurrentTextValue) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find NumberOfDoors then look for the value

Here I use a ternary operator for the output

```js
const carj = '[{ "Description": "SAAB 900 S CONVERTIBLE", "RegistrationYear": "1993", "CarMake": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "CarModel": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "MakeDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "ModelDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "EngineSize": { "CurrentTextValue": "1985" }, "BodyStyle": { "CurrentTextValue": "Motorbike" }, "FuelType": { "CurrentTextValue": "PETROL" }, "Variant": "", "Colour": "BLACK", "VehicleIdentificationNumber": "YS3AD75S1P7004905", "KType": "", "EngineNumber": "B202S3M03P032338" }]';


const carj2 = $.parseJSON(carj);

const NumberOfDoors = carj2[0].NumberOfDoors;
console.log( NumberOfDoors ? NumberOfDoors.CurrentTextValue : 'I don\'t have doors');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The newest JS in 2020 can do [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Note the `?` in `["NumberOfDoors"]?`

```js
const carj = '[{ "Description": "SAAB 900 S CONVERTIBLE", "RegistrationYear": "1993", "CarMake": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "CarModel": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "MakeDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "ModelDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "EngineSize": { "CurrentTextValue": "1985" }, "BodyStyle": { "CurrentTextValue": "Motorbike" }, "FuelType": { "CurrentTextValue": "PETROL" }, "Variant": "", "Colour": "BLACK", "VehicleIdentificationNumber": "YS3AD75S1P7004905", "KType": "", "EngineNumber": "B202S3M03P032338" }]';


const carj2 = $.parseJSON(carj);

const NumberOfDoors = carj2[0].NumberOfDoors?.CurrentTextValue || 0
console.log(NumberOfDoors ||  'I don\'t have doors');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var carj = '[{ "Description": "SAAB 900 S CONVERTIBLE", "RegistrationYear": "1993", "CarMake": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "CarModel": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "MakeDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "SAAB" }, "ModelDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "900 S CONVERTIBLE" }, "EngineSize": { "CurrentTextValue": "1985" }, "BodyStyle": { "CurrentTextValue": "Motorbike" }, "FuelType": { "CurrentTextValue": "PETROL" }, "Variant": "", "Colour": "BLACK", "VehicleIdentificationNumber": "YS3AD75S1P7004905", "KType": "", "EngineNumber": "B202S3M03P032338" }]';

carj2 = $.parseJSON(carj);

// Method 1
if ("numberOfDoors" in carj2[0]) {
    console.log(carj2[0].NumberOfDoors.CurrentTextValue);
} else {
    console.log('i dont have doors');
}

// Method 2
console.log(carj2[0].NumberOfDoors?.CurrentTextValue || "i dont have doors");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The 'in' operator can be used to check if an object contains a certain key.
The ? operator can also be used to make sure JavaScript is not trying to fetch and use an undefined value.

Comment: It is called _optional chaining_ as I said in my answer...